# Export Xls workbook using r

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, xls

I know it is possible to produce xlsx workbook using R(OpenXlSX)

But is there a way to produce xls workbook using R ?

I know export is possible but for a xls sheet but I need a workbook.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/package=WriteXLS

Comment: Any working example? Where, we add a workbook and then add sheets to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert a xlsx file to a xls file with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
path_Excel_File1 <- "D:\\file1.xlsx"
path_Excel_File_Output <- "D:\\file1.xls"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk1 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File1)

xlWbk1$SaveAs(path_Excel_File_Output, -4143) # saving as .xls
```